# Piping a line of the file read with while read loop

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, cat, cut

I am trying to read each line of the file and then assign some parts of it to variables. A line itself is read as a variable so I need to process a variable input say for cat which seems to be impossible. I tried echoing but it looks like it doesn't do what I need.

This is how it looks like with `cat`:

`cat $LINE | cut -f1`

`cat $LINE | cut -f4| sed s/\.pdf$/\.html/`

Hopefully the problem has been put clearly enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may be mis-thinking this.  (Mis-thinking is a little like over-thinking, but misdirected.)  Read [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271976), and then tell us what you *really* want to do.

Comment: May be you were right but it didn't help me. Hope you can help me next time ;)

Comment: X = "I am trying to read each line of the file and then assign some parts of it to variables."  Y = "A line is read as a variable so I need to process a variable ...".  OK, I'm sorry; you ***did*** tell us what you really wanted to do — or at least you hinted at it.  But then the last 90% of your question is cluttered with your flawed approach to doing it.  I hope that, next time you ask a question, you'll be able to tell us ***clearly*** what you *really* want to do, and focus your question on that.    :-|    ⁠

Answer (score 0):

`cat` takes a filename as its argument. You definitely need `echo`. What you may have wrong is that the line read will be space-separated, so `cut` needs a `-d " "`.

However, why not use the `-r` option of `read` ?

```
$ read -r NAME FNAME AGE FILE < file
$ echo $NAME
Doe
$ echo $FNAME
John
$ echo $AGE
36
$ echo $FILE
johns_letter.pdf
$ echo $FILE | sed -e "s/.pdf/.html/"
johns_letter.html
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You've helped me greatly when I was floating in the middle of desperation and panic making mistakes and not being able to see them :) the key thing was reading a line into variables.

Comment: Glad to have helped. One SE way to say 'thank you' is to upvote and accept the answer! ;-)